# jpackage install to directory with read/write/excecute access on linux?

Tags: java, linux, installation, deployment, jpackage

On windows, you can achieve this by using `--win-per-user-install` and the msi installer installs to directories like `%LOCAL_APP_DATA%/<app-name>`. This directory has read write access for other programs by default. I want to use the equivalent for linux. So what is the equivalent for %LOCAL_APP_DATA%/ for linux, having read write permissions by default, and how do I tell jpackage to make the installer install there?

I am packaging a jar file which manages the update of the application's files and installs them from the server. All this is done in the same directory where it is installed. I cannot change the code in this jar file, so any java code solutions can't be done. I need to achieve this using jpackage.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell JPackage to add pre-install, post-install, pre-remove and post-remove scripts into the deb package. But on it's own it won't do this.

That means you have to provide the code, and here you can define whatever you need: additional directories, correct privileges, ...

See also [Override jpackage Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6)